# PHP preg_match escaping character

Tags: php, regex

So I'm having the following issue with regular expressions:

What I am trying to achieve: Get the last element of the namespace, in this case "BAZ"

To do so I am using the regular expression below:

```
preg_match("/[^\\]*$/", 'Foo\Bar\Baz', $output);
```

For some reason I get this error:

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 6

Comment: You're escaping the square bracket.

Comment: You don't need a regex for this, `echo end(explode('\\', 'Foo\Bar\Baz'));`.

Comment: Agreed .... RegEx should be the last option ..! @chris85 write an answer, I will give you +1 `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to double escape `\\` because in PHP regex is entered as string where which requires each literal `\` as `\\` and regex engine needs additional escaping of each `\` so you end up with 4 `\`:

```
preg_match('/[^\\\\]*$/', 'Foo\Bar\Baz', $output);
```

Comment: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/bIOi8)

Comment: Yes I just added some explanation of escaping

Comment: Odd .. [**three** back-slash works too](https://3v4l.org/KWcjX)

Comment: @Shafizadeh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28062568/why-3-backslash-equal-4-backslash-in-php

Comment: Yes I know 3 `\\\` work as well in PHP but it is recommended to use 4 `\\\\`