# PHP - regex to match and capture year from DD\/MM\/YYYY but can't escape the backslash

Tags: php, regex, date

I have a date in the format:

```
DD\/MM\/YYYY
```

eg:

```
28\/01\/2017
```

and I am trying to pattern match it and output the year.

I was struggling so I thought I would remove the / and test that but despite having a match that works in every online tester I have used. It won't work in my script.

so.

My new string is:

```
$datestring = "28\01\2017";
```

and I'm trying to keep it simple by just trying to capture the "DD\" with:

```
    $datestring = "28\01\2017";
    $regmatch = '/(^[0-9]{2}\\\\)/';

    if (preg_match($regmatch,$datestring,$matches)) {
echo "<strong>The match from the preg_match is: " . $matches[0] . "</strong><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<strong>No match</strong><br><br>";
    }
```

But this also doesn't work and says "No match". I was under the impression that to match a \ in PHP I need to escape it 3 times hence:

```
\\\\
```

If I remove the four backslashes and just use:

```
$regmatch = '/(^[0-9]{2})/';
```

it matches and outputs "28" so I know the rest of the code works.

Whats odd is that in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Nm8sdE/3) it works with just two backslashes but if I put this in my script I get the error:

Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

EDIT:

The reason why I have the date in this format is because I am pulling GeoJSOn out of a csv and this is the output:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -3.224752,
                    55.891831
                ]
            },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "team": "TVMRT",
                "year": "2018",
                "category": "misper",
                "grid": "NS 929 680",
                "day": "Saturday",
                "date": "28\/01\/2017",
                "type": "Missing Person",
                "area": "Armadale, ground to west",
                "sex": "Male",
                "age": "47",
                "members": "19",
                "hours": "71",
                "description": "Description goes here."
            }
        },
```

**EDIT 3**

By jove I have it!

I know have the "/" back in the date string so it looks like:

"28/01/2017"

The new test is:

```
$datestring = "28\/01\/2017";
    echo "datestring is: " . $datestring ."<br>";
    $regmatch = '~^[0-9]{2}\\\/[0-9]{2}\\\/([0-9]{4})~';
    if (preg_match($regmatch,$datestring,$matches)) {
echo "<strong>The match from the preg_match is: " . $matches[1] . "</strong><br><br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<strong>No match</strong><br><br>";
    }
```

And I now get:

> datestring is: 28/01/2017 The match from the preg_match is: 2017

My new question is. Why is this working with just two backslashes? ie:

```
\\\/
```

is matching

```
\/
```

Comment: Care to explain why you have that source string format? This looks like a context mishap.

Comment: I've tried: $regmatch = '(^[0-9]{2}\\\\)'; but it just says no match

Comment: How about decoding the JSON instead of this regex BS? http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Your new question [already has an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28062664/300836).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget you need to escape the backslashes in your test data, too!

```
$datestring = "28\\01\\2017";
```

...will give you a literal string of '28\01\2017'. As it stands you're putting weird control codes (ASCII `0x1` and whatever `\2017` is interpreted as by PHP!) instead of the backslashes.

Try echoing your original `$datestring` to see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, very interesting. Use `add_slashes($input)` it the data is (user) input.

Comment: Good spot. I've edited my question and put back in the "/" in the date format but still can't get this work in my script whereas it does work in regex101

Comment: Thanks Matt. Your answer put me on a long journey which eventually resulted in me resolving the issue. It was strenuous and I often went round in circles but I have it working and I'm smiling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How to extract the year value from a `DD\/MM\/YYYY` formmatted string?  You don't need to use regex when there is an equivalent string function to do the job.

```
$date='28\\01\\2017';
echo substr($date,-4);  // output: 2017
```

This method doesn't give a hoot about whether or not the slashes are escaped.

Regex functions should only be used when other functions fail to concisely and accurately do the job.

Frankly, I can't believe no one else mentioned this simpler/better approach.

---

Beyond the above best practice, if you want to know about writing correct patterns, here are a couple of vital details:

1. Characters within the pattern (`/`) that are also used as pattern delimiters (`/`) will cause the pattern to "end" early and foul things up.
2. A backslash (`\`) is used to escape the character that immediately follows them.  If you want a backslash to be treated literally by the regex engine, you must escape it.

These patterns will work:

`/\d{2}\\\/\d{2}\\\/\d{4}/` -- use `\` to escape `\` and `/`

`~\d{2}\\/\d{2}\\/\d{4}~` -- alter the pattern delimiters to avoid escaping `/`, use `\` to escape `/`

`/\d{2}\Q\/\E\d{2}\Q\/\E\d{4}/` -- force regex to treat all characters literally between `\Q` and `\E`

`/\d{2}\D+\d{2}\D+\d{4}/` -- loosen the pattern to matche one or more non-digit numbers between date number components; since the source of the data is rather trustworthy, you can improve pattern brevity by further loosening the pattern to: `/\d+\D+\d+\D+\d+/`